# mySQL - Does Int(9.455.487) take more space than string(John) in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I understood that in a database an int takes less space than a string. But what if the int is really longer than the string. For example 9.455.487 vs "John". Which one will take more space? TY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), size of `int` is 4 bytes, whereas for `char` it is "M × w bytes, 0 <= M <= 255, where w is the number of bytes required for the maximum-length character in the character set." and M is the declared column size.

So when you talk of how much space is taken, the `int` will take up 4 bytes for a value as long as the value is within the range of `int`. A string like "John", if declared as `char(4)` will take up 4 * w bytes, so at least 4 bytes assuming w is 1.

Long story short, the size of a number is not how many characters long it is when you write it out, but the number of bytes to represent it in the binary form.

Comment: It may be useful to note the difference between a string and a number -- as in, the former is usually an array of the latter.

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware of what "int" ([integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)) is and what [strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29) are. Integer *always* has some length and that length means how many *bytes* are in it's *binary* representation. On the other hand, strings are *sequences* of bytes. So, depending of [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), each symbol may be one or more bytes.

The thing that `9.455.487` is "longer" than `"John"` is irrelevant here. What is relevant - is how DBMS (or whatever other environment) will represent those things. You're seeing "longer" integer versus "shorter" string while it's not so, it's only a matter of "screen" representation (i.e. what you see on the screen).

Answering question - for MySQL, [`INT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) is 4 bytes, while string data types may have *dynamic* length - such as [`VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html). Static string length date type is `CHAR` and from that viewpoint, your number and your string will have *same* length (4 bytes). Strings and integers are just different things to compare for "length". And visual representation should not confuse you. This entities have different internal structure, and, therefore, should not be compared on "length" according to their visual representation.

Also, you should be aware that not always integer will have 4 bytes length - since even in MySQL your number may belong to, for example, `BIGINT` data type (which is 8 bytes length). And, as mentioned above, for strings there's also encoding issue. For instance, [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded string may have two (or even more) bytes to represent some non-ASCII symbols. In this case each symbol will add more that 1 byte to total string length.